# eclipse, could not find PdCore.apk when trying to install libpd

Tags: android, puredata

could not find PdCore.apk error when compiling.

I've followed instructions from:

http://createdigitalnoise.com/discussion/1415/eclipse-could-not-find-pdcore-apk

and here:

https://github.com/libpd/libpd/issues/22

I've got all the SDK's of android.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as said in the first link relates to eclipse trying to manage the git project when it should be used only with the command line interface. Egit does this just when you import the project to eclipse.

To prevent egit to update the project and loose the .apk what I did was to copy all the git content to a folder without the hidden git folder that tells eclipse that that is a git project.

Eclipse imported it as a normal project (without git) and I could be able to run the library.

Hope this will be useful to others.